# How to make the timer goes faster than 1 second

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a text that gets updated every second I am using

```
@State var timeRemaining = 10
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
Text("Time Left: \(self.timeRemaining)").onReceive(timer) { _ in
                        if self.timeRemaining > 0 {
                            self.timeRemaining -= 1
                        }
                        if self.timeRemaining <= 0 {
                            print("Time is up!")
                        }
                    }
```

But I want it to go faster than just every one second.
Thank you

Comment: Try "every: 0.5"

Comment: I tried that but what I meant, how to make it go like in milliseconds, I even tried 0.001 but it did not work

Comment: I'm not sure what is the actual precision there, but you can try 0.005 for 5 milliseconds for example. Just make sure that you're not doing too much work on the main thread...

Comment: I found it when I call timer in `.onReceive(timer)`I was calling another one, I did not notice having two timers one called timer and the other time

Comment: The screen only draws every 16ms at best, so a Timer faster than that isn't useful for UI updates. Timers are not intended to be that precise in any case. The way you determine how much time has passed is to subtract the start time from the current time. You can't rely on counting down some value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```
let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

I was just calling another timer without noticing the different names.

Answer (score 2):

Do:

```
  let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1 / 2, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
```

the timer will only take whole numbers not decimals. so you can do some math and figure how much faster you want it